# How to pass data or object by window.open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, crystal-reports

I need pass data or object (Criteria) from AngularJS to Crystal Report Viewer in asp.net Web

**AngularJS Code:**

```
$scope.OnPrint = function() {
 $window.open('http://localhost:89/', '_blank');
};
```

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query string:

```
$scope.OnPrint = function() {
 var param1 = '192';
 var param2 = 'userReport';
 $window.open('http://localhost:89/?param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2, '_blank');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use query string:

```
$scope.OnPrint = function() {
 $window.open('http://localhost:89/?param1=value&param2=value', '_blank');
};
```